# Why does my script only save one out of the 40 objects that I insert?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm scraping data and putting it in a database.  The problem is that only one object gets saved, while I know there are about 40 objects collected.

How do I get my script to save all the objects?

```
class PresstvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_presstv_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, items, spider):
        session = self.Session()

        for title, link, date in zip(items['title'], items['link'], items['date']):
            print(title, link, date)
            item = Presstv(title = title, link = link, date = date)

            if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item.link).first() == None:
                try:
                    session.add(item)
                    session.commit()
                    logger.info('Item saved')
                except:
                    session.rollback()
                    raise
                finally:
                    session.close()

                return item
```

```
presstv_url = "http://www.url.ir/Default/Section/1"
presstv_xpath = '//html/body/section/div/div/section/div[2]/section/ul'
presstv_pipeline = PresstvPipeline()

def presstv_extract_item(element):
    return {
        'title': element.xpath('li/div/div/p/text()'),
        'link': element.xpath('li/div/div/a/@href'),
        'date': element.xpath('li/div/div/div/text()'),
    }

def spider_html(input_url, extract_function, input_xpath, pipeline):
    tree = lxml.html.parse(input_url)

    for element in tree.xpath(input_xpath):
        pipeline.process_item(extract_function(element), None)

presstv = spider_html(presstv_url, presstv_extract_item, presstv_xpath, presstv_pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the session inside the for loop, so nothing will happen on it in the subsequent iterations.  Actually it's worse than that, since you're returning the item inside the loop, meaning the loop won't even execute the rest of the iterations.  Move the rollback/close handling outside the loop.  Move the return outside as well.  You don't need to rollback, since the session will be closed anyway.

```
def process_item(self, items, spider):
    session = self.Session()

    try:
        for title, link, date in zip(items['title'], items['link'], items['date']):
            print(title, link, date)
            item = Presstv(title = title, link = link, date = date)

            if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item.link).first() == None:
                session.add(item)
                session.commit()
                logger.info('Item saved')
    finally:
        session.close()

    return items
```